# Deployment Issue in Mean Io on Azure

Tags: azure, mean.io

I have deployed the mean app on azure ubuntu box. I have installed all the modules and dependencies of node using npm install and bower dependencies using bower install. The app in logs show that it is started on port 3000 but when I see the browser console it show this error:

```
aggregated.js:11 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=mean&p1=Error%3A%20…
http%3A%2F%2Fsecondreveiw.cloudapp.net%2Fmodules%2Faggregated.js%3A26%3A19)
```

I have aggregated true in my development.js config file.

By the way the app is working fine locally on my windows machine.

Comment: Do you use minified version of angular? That exact error can be of any nature. Try to use full-fledged version - it should show more information.

Comment: I have used the full-fledged version but stills the same error.